# cakephp probleme with pagination and file_get_contents

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-api, cakephp-2.0

I develop a back-end for a mobile application with cakephp

I have a function that list cities and I want to calculate distance from the user the this cities the code is:

```
$origins='origins=casablanca,maroc';
    $destinations='&destinations=';
    $url='http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?';

    $this->paginate = array(
            'limit' => 10,
            'fields'=>array('cityId','cityFileName','cityName','stateId','stateFileName','stateName',
                'countryCode','countryFileName','countryName','count(id) as num_hotels'),
            'order' => 'num_hotels desc',
            'group' =>array('cityId')

    );
    $hotels = $this->paginate();

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($hotels); ++$i) {

        $destination=($i==0?'':'|');

        $destination.=$hotels[$i]['Hotel']['cityName'].','.$hotels[$i]['Hotel']['countryName'];

        $destinations.=$destination;
    }

    $url.=$origins.$destinations.'&mode=driving&language=fr-FR&sensor=false';

    $json = file_get_contents($url,0,null,null);
    $details = json_decode($json, TRUE);

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($hotels); ++$i) {
        $hotels = Set::insert($hotels, $i.'.Hotel.distance',$details['rows']['0']['elements']['0']['distance']['value']);
    }

    $this->set(compact('hotels'));
    $this -> viewPath = "hotels";
    $this -> render("json/index","json/default");
```

the problem is when i test with the first page (pagination) the result is good but when i access to others page >=2 i got this warning and i cant get the distance

the error is :

```
Warning (2): file_get_contents(http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=casablanca,maroc&destinations=Zagora,Morocco|Meknes,Morocco|Chefchaouen,Morocco|Tinghir,Morocco|M'hamid,Morocco|El Jadida,Morocco|Erfoud,Morocco|Skoura,Morocco|Tetouan,Morocco|Imlil,Morocco&mode=driving&language=fr-FR&sensor=false) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request
```

[APP\Controller\ApiController.php, line 81]

> Code Context
>
> $origins  =   "origins=casablanca,maroc"
>   $destinations =   "&destinations=Zagora,Morocco|Meknes,Morocco|Chefchaouen,Morocco|Tinghir,Morocco|M'hamid,Morocco|El
>   Jadida,Morocco|Erfoud,Morocco|Skoura,Morocco|Tetouan,Morocco|Imlil,Morocco"
>   $url  =   "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=casablanca,maroc&destinations=Zagora,Morocco|Meknes,Morocco|Chefchaouen,Morocco|Tinghir,Morocco|M'hamid,Morocco|El
>   Jadida,Morocco|Erfoud,Morocco|Skoura,Morocco|Tetouan,Morocco|Imlil,Morocco&mode=driving&language=fr-FR&sensor=false"
>   $hotels   =   array(  array(  "Hotel" => array(),     array() ),  array(
>     "Hotel" => array(),     array() ),  array(  "Hotel" => array(),     array()
>   ),    array(  "Hotel" => array(),     array() ),  array(  "Hotel" =>
>   array(),  array() ),  array(  "Hotel" => array(),     array() ),  array(
>     "Hotel" => array(),     array() ),  array(  "Hotel" => array(),     array()
>   ),    array(  "Hotel" => array(),     array() ),  array(  "Hotel" =>
>   array(),  array() ) ) $i  =   10 $destination =   "|Imlil,Morocco"
>   $http_response_header =   array(  "HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request",
>     "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8",   "Content-Length: 925",
>     "Date: Wed, 08 Aug 2012 15:42:43 GMT",  "Server: GFE/2.0" )
>
> file_get_contents - [internal], line ?? ApiController::yassine() -
>   APP\Controller\ApiController.php, line 81
>   ReflectionMethod::invokeArgs() - [internal], line ??
>   Controller::invokeAction() - CORE\Cake\Controller\Controller.php, line
>   473 Dispatcher::_invoke() - CORE\Cake\Routing\Dispatcher.php, line 104
>   Dispatcher::dispatch() - CORE\Cake\Routing\Dispatcher.php, line 86
>   [main] - APP\webroot\index.php, line 96

Comment: the solution is to encode destinations   $destination.=urlencode($hotels[$i]['Hotel']['cityName'].','.$hotels[$i]['Hotel']['countryName']);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must correct this line.

```
$url.="origins=" .  urlencode($origins). "&destinations=" .
      urlencode($destinations)."&mode=driving&language=fr-FR&sensor=false";
```